# Excel Pivot Series and Points

Tags: excel, pivot

I have a table:
[Source Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5xc4.png)

When I create a Pivot Chart (or Table), and drag/drop the month fields (ex. "Oct-21") into Legend(Series) and Axis (Categories) (or rows or columns in the Pivot Table), Excel will automatically create the "Month" field from the table's selected columns, which I then use for parts of my Chart/Table.

But for some reason, it's taking one of the numbers that's supposed to be in October, and classifying it as December.  If you look at the piece of data in the Chart (hover over the bar), it will say Series "Sum of Oct-21" Point **"Dec"** Value "80000".  All the other data is fine, and I've even tried opening a new workbook, cut+copying over the data and recreating the Pivot Tables/Charts.

How can I correct this misclassification?

Comment: If you double click the value in the Pivot table it should produce a worksheet with all the data for that point on it.  Have a look at the dates and see if they are December.  It might be that the date format is getting confused - eg 10/12/2021 would be 10th December 2021 in Australia but 12th October 2021 in the US.

Comment: That's the thing.  Doing that, it still indicates that the data is under the Oct-21 column.  It's really odd since the rest of the table, which I originally manually created (I looked at the very original source and hand-typed in, not cut-paste) has no other problems.  Is there some way to change the Series and Point "properties" on a piece of data?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it should be something like this or not, refer the image, the expected invoicing date is on 31st Oct 21 while Actual Invoicing is on 1st Dec 21, hence you might have considered one of the date columns, and where you need to consider the other date column as well, please let me know, if i am wrong here.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, playing around with it more, it seems like the "Months"  field that automatically gets generated (has the word "OCT" vs the words "Oct-21 or Oct-212") is being created based on the Actual Date column and not the Expected Date column.  Any ideas about how to change that?  I've tried to drag the Expected Date field in first, or drag the Actual Date field in first, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Sir, try the way I have shown you, it should work, the way you are trying to do, shall create a unique month field for each of the same month, since both the headers are same .

Comment: @lljc00 one other way may be using Power Query, to unpivot the data, and then use it as a connection to create Pivot Table & Charts, i shall try the same, and show, give me some time!